# Smoothing Function in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-2.x, signal-processing

```
def smoothen(heightProfile, travelTime):
    newHeightProfile = []

    # Berechne einen gleitenden Mittelwert
    smoothingInterval = 30 * travelTime

    for i in xrange(smoothingInterval):
        heightProfile.append(heightProfile[-1])

    for i in xrange(len(heightProfile) - smoothingInterval):
        mean = 0
        for j in xrange(i, i + smoothingInterval):
            mean += heightProfile[j]
        newHeightProfile.append(mean/smoothingInterval)

    return newHeightProfile
```

Input:

- `heightProfile`: an array of the size `travelTime` * 60
- `travelTime`: an integer

`travelTime` can be, for example, `500`. `heightProfile` contains an array of random numbers of the size `travelTime * 60`. The height profile should describe the height of a random landscape. The function is used to smoothen the values.

However, this code is very slow and expensive, even when using `xrange`:

- Tests for travel time: 500
- CPython: 38.3s
- Pypy: 0.98s

Questions:

1. Is there a construct in this code which is very inefficient?
2. Would this be faster if I were to implement this function in C?

Any other recommendations for improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are calculating the mean each time in the loop, so that's slice + sum for each of the `len(heightProfile) - smoothingInterval` iterations. We can remove this by calculating the mean of first `smoothingInterval` items and then inside of the loop simply subtract current **i**<sup>th</sup> item from the sum of the previous mean and add (i + smoothingInterval)<sup>th</sup> item to the sum and calculate the mean for the current window. With this approach we can do this in almost linear time.

Also as you're using Python 2 don't forget to add this line at the top of the file, otherwise normal division will result in integer division.

```
from __future__ import division
```

You can replace:

```
for i in range(smoothingInterval):
        heightProfile.append(heightProfile[-1])
```

with:

```
heightProfile.extend([heightProfile[-1]]*smoothingInterval)
```

If `smoothingInterval` is very huge then consider passing a generator expression to `list.extend`, but in most cases `[heightProfile[-1]]*smoothingInterval` is as fast as you can get:

```
last_val = heightProfile[-1]
heightProfile.extend(last_val for _ in xrange(smoothingInterval))
```

---

**Full Code:**

```
from __future__ import division


def smoothen_fast(heightProfile, travelTime):

    smoothingInterval = 30 * travelTime

    heightProfile.extend([heightProfile[-1]]*smoothingInterval)
    # Get the mean of first `smoothingInterval` items  
    first_mean = sum(heightProfile[:smoothingInterval]) / smoothingInterval
    newHeightProfile = [first_mean]

    for i in xrange(len(heightProfile)-smoothingInterval-1):
        prev = heightProfile[i]  # the item to be subtracted from the sum
        new = heightProfile[i+smoothingInterval] # item to be added
        # Calculate the sum of previous items by multiplying
        # last mean with smoothingInterval
        prev_sum = newHeightProfile[-1] * smoothingInterval
        new_sum = prev_sum - prev + new
        mean = new_sum / smoothingInterval
        newHeightProfile.append(mean)

    return newHeightProfile
```

---

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> heightProfile = sample(xrange(1, 10**5), 10**4)
>>> travelTime = 1000
>>> %timeit smoothen(heightProfile[:], travelTime)
1 loops, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop
>>> %timeit smoothen_fast(heightProfile[:], travelTime)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop
```

Note that in my function call I am passing a slice of the list because we are modifying the passed list object using its `.extend` method, which is usually a not a good idea unless the caller expects such modifications.